# Setting up print statement in Tox

Tags: python, tox

I am writing test case scenarios for my project. In tox.ini I have mentioned envlogdir for getting the logs

```
[tox]
envlogdir = /home/user/testlog
```

while running tox, I am getting logs that are based on installation. I need to get print statements that I gave in my code.

Is there any way , we can print the statements in console or in log directory.

Or do we need to configure Logger to write every output in DEBUG or INFO mode.

Can someone guide.

Comment: which test runner are you using? (ie pytest,nose...)

Answer (score 1):

Tox prints all standard output on console while executing commands under `commands` section. A tox.ini sample file which works for me is below.

```
[tox]
minversion = 1.6
envlist = py34

[testenv]
setenv = 
    PYTHONPATH = {toxinidir}

commands = 
    python -c "print('Hello srinath')"
    python abc.py
```

In my case, `Hello srinath` gets printed on console. And any print from abc.py whould also be on console. Hope it helps :)